# How to get information about WCF service client from operation implementation?

Tags: wcf, client-certificates

I especially need to get client's certificate used to call service's method. This is to react differently for different clients.

Answer (score 1):

In your operation code, you can examine things like:

```
OperationContext.Current
```

or

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current
```

but I'm not sure if you can access the actual client certificate from those.

The `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity` will contain an `IIdentity` for the current caller - if it's NULL, then you're dealing with an anonymous call. Otherwise, the PrimaryIdentity will be one of several possible identity types, depending on how the calling user was authenticated - it could be a Windows identity, or something else - depending on your scenario.

See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/suwatch/archive/2007/04/06/x509-and-wcxf-security.aspx) for a few more tidbits of information on X.509 and WCF.